# Form gets submitted before validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am just starting programming with HTML, PHP and JavaScript. My data gets passed onto database but it's not getting validated before it gets submitted. 
The file name='logout.html'
Here is the validation code :

```
    <script>function Submit1()
 {
   var emailRegex = /^[A-Za-z0-9._]*\@[A-Za-z]*\.[A-Za-z]{2,5}$/;
   var fname = document.form.Name.value,
   lname = document.form.LastName.value,
   femail = document.form.Email.value,
   freemail = document.form.enterEmail.value,
   fpassword = document.form.Password.value,
   fmonth = document.form.birthday_month.value,
   fday = document.form.birthday_day.value,
   fyear = document.form.birthday_year.value;

  if( fname == "" )
   {
     document.form.Name.focus() ;
     document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the       first name";
     return false;
   }
 if( lname == "" )
   {
     document.form.LastName.focus() ;
   document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the last name";
     return false;
   }

   if (femail == "" )
 {
  document.form.Email.focus();
  document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the email";
  return false;
  }else if(!emailRegex.test(femail)){
  document.form.Email.focus();
  document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the valid email";
  return false;
  }

   if (freemail == "" )
 {
  document.form.enterEmail.focus();
  document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Re-enter the email";
  return false;
  }else if(!emailRegex.test(freemail)){
  document.form.enterEmail.focus();
  document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Re-enter the valid email";
  return false;
  }

  if(freemail !=  femail){
   document.form.enterEmail.focus();
   document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "emails are not matching, re-enter again";
   return false;
   }


 if(fpassword == "")
  {
   document.form.Password.focus();
   document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the password";
   return false;
  }

   if (fmonth == "") {
        document.form.birthday_month.focus();
  document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "select the birthday month";
        return false;
     }
  if (fday == "") {
        document.form.birthday_day.focus();
  document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "select the birthday day";
        return false;
     }
  if (fyear == "") {
        document.form.birthday_year.focus();
  document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "select the birthday year";
        return false;
     }
  if(document.form.radiobutton[0].checked == false && document.form.radiobutton[1].checked == false){
    document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "select your gender";
    return false;
   }
  if(fname != '' && lname != '' && femail != '' && freemail != '' && fpassword != '' && fmonth != '' && fday != '' && fyear != ''){
    return true;
   document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "form submitted successfully";
   }

}</script>
```

And here is the code of my form :

```
<form name="form" onsubmit="return submit1();" action="connectivity-sign-up.php" method="POST" >
       <div id="errorBox"></div>
        <input type="text" name="Name" value="" placeholder="First Name"  class="input_name" >
        <input type="text" name="LastName" value="" placeholder="Last Name" class="input_name" >

      </div>
      <div id="email_form">
        <input type="text" name="Email" value=""  placeholder="Your Email" class="input_email">
      </div>
      <div id="Re_email_form">
        <input type="text" name="enterEmail" value=""  placeholder="Re-enter Email" class="input_Re_email">
      </div>
      <div id="password_form">
        <input type="password" name="Password" value=""  placeholder="New Password" class="input_password">
      </div>
      <!--birthday details start-->
      <div>
        <h3 class="birthday_title">Birthday</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        <select name="birthday_month" >
          <option value="" selected >Month</option>
          <option value="1">Jan</option>
          <option value="2">Feb</option>
          <option value="3">Mar</option>
          <option value="4">Apr</option>
          <option value="5">May</option>
        </select>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select name="birthday_day" >
          <option value="" selected>Day</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select name="birthday_year">
          <option value="" selected>Year</option>
          <option value="2013">2013</option>
          <option value="2012">2012</option>
          <option value="2011">2011</option>
          <option value="2010">2010</option>
          <option value="2009">2009</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <!--birthday details ends-->
      <div id="radio_button">
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="Female">
        <label >Female</label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="Male">
        <label >Male</label>
      </div>
       <div>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
      </div>
     </form>
```

Help would be sincerely appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your function name is `Submit1` but in your form tag you use `submit1` you know that `javascript` is **case sensitive** language so you have to use one of them
Just change `onsubmit="return Submit1();"` or change your function name to `submit1`

Comment: Thanks for that. Sorry about the obvious mistake